# Need to pull the cell's info or mark it as "x" if there's specific text containing in a different column

Tags: excel, indexing, find, match, sumifs

I've following data set:
For Account 1, if column 6 contains NBA, column 4 (NBA) should be checked as "x or pull "NBA or NBA1" - whatever version of NBA it is; 
If Account 2 has MNM, put an "x" on the column MNM.... similarly for each account down the column.. I tried putting index, small functions but keep getting blanks. Any thoughts?

```
  Column1      Column 2      ABC    NBA   MNM  Column 6   
  Account1       CNN                x          NBA
  Account2       N-H                      x    MNM5
  Account3       ABC is good                   ABC
  Account4       H-I                           ABC2
  Account5       TI                            MNM3  
  Account6       N-T                           NM
  Account7       BE                            NBA1
```

Comment: What do the numbers signify? ie: NBA1 - it is not clear what you want to happen here. Do you just want to put a check under "NBA", whether it says "NBA" or "NBA1"? Or do you want it to actually fill a different column in that case?

Comment: NBA1 and NBA2 or NBA3 would be subset of NBA...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the different 'versions' in column 6 mean nothing, and count as a 'regular' result (ie: NBA is the same for these purposes as NBA1), see the following:

Put this formula in Column3, row 2 (ABC Account1) and drag down/right:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($F2,C$1)),"","x")
```

This says: if you find the text of the current header column in row 1, within the item in column F for this particular row, then put "x". If that search produces an error, show "".

Answer (score 1):

Im trying to ascertain what you actual are trying to acheive, doe the numbers at the end of your data in column six mean something or does MNM5 still mean mnm.

If so I went a slightly different route to Grade Eh Bacon.

I added another column called truth of which I used an if statement to look for the "ABC","NBA","MNM"

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("NBA",F2)),"N",(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MNM",F2)),"M",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ABC",F2)),"A"," "))))
```

The F2 Reference is, Column 6 first row of data.

I then went back into your "ABC","NBA","MNM" columns and added:

```
=IF($G2="A","X"," ")
```

"A" is the true value for ABC.
"N" is the true value for NBA.
"M" is the true value for MNM.

If the truth column under each prospective column has this Variable then it will mark the cell "X"

Comment: That's exactly how I did.. Works perfectly fine to pull "X". However I want to pull the exact fields in there.. For Example.. MNM1 or MNM2 or MNM3 are subsets of MNM. Similarly NBA1, NBA2 or NBA3 would be subset of NBA.. same for ABC..

Comment: That worked.. just for knowledge purposes, what if I have 2 rows for   Account 1 - one for NBA1 and another for NBA2. Can we concatenate it and in the column for NBA pull both the responses - NBA1 and NBA2

Comment: It isnt looking for an NBA 1 or 2 just and NBA the number on the end if its just a ID reference shouldnt matter. The account also doesnt make any difference as its not being referenced.
Are you looking to return X as NBA1,2,3 under NBA?

Comment: I got workaround to return X as NBA1,2,3 under NBA. Looking to return NBA1 or NBA2 or NBA3 or both NBA1 and NBA2 if it's the one.